# MySql query with subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm having trouble trying to make a simple query.
My tables are:

user

```
+-------+----------+
| id    | username |
+-------+----------+
```

messages

```
+-------+-------------+------------+--------+
| id    | receiver_id | sender_id  | text   |
+-------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

I need to get all messages coming from or received from a SEPECIFIC user (knowing his username).
But also I need to get the receiver and sender username.

I used

```
SELECT *  from user U, messages M where (M.sender_id OR M.receiver_id)=(select id from user where username = 'Guy1') group by M.id
```

This works but now I need their username so I thought about something like:

```
SELECT * from user U, messages M, (select username as Sender from user U1, messages M1 where M1.sender_id= U1.id)as Sub where (M.sender_id OR M.receiver_id)=(select id from user where username = 'Guy1') group by M.id
```

but it's not giving me what I need, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

In the result I need something like:

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+
| text  | receiver_Username | sender_Username  | 
+-------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: select username, receiver_id, sender_id, text from user left join messages on user.id = messages.receiver_id

Comment: select username, receiver_id, sender_id, text from user left join messages on user.id = messages.sender_id

Comment: Maybe I didn't express well, I need to get username of sender_id and username of receiver_id and the text. But only where user is = User1
All these queries you posted doesn't do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following query will get the result you need by joining two times messages table with user table. One for the senders and one for the receivers

```
  SELECT  messages.text,sender.username,receiver.username   from messages
  inner join user as sender on sender.id = messages.sender_id
  inner join  user as receiver on receiver.id = messages.receiver_id
```

Comment: Thank you. That's actually working (instead of all other answers) just edited to add the user part, so   
  `SELECT  messages.text,sender.username as Sender,receiver.username as Receiver  from messages
  inner join user as sender on sender.id = messages.sender_id
  inner join  user as receiver on receiver.id = messages.receiver_id WHERE ((sender.username or receiver.username)="Guy") `

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't express well, I need to get username of sender_id and username of receiver_id and the text. But only where user is = User1 All these queries you posted doesn't do this –  Gabriele Prestifilippo 6 secs ago

Username and Text of sender_id:

```
SELECT u.username, m.text FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON u.id = m.sender_id
WHERE u.username = 'Some_User';
```

Username and Text of receiver_id:

```
SELECT u.username, m.text FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON u.id = m.receiver_id
WHERE u.username = 'Some_User';
```

Combined:

```
SELECT u.username, m.text, x.text FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON u.id = m.receiver_id
LEFT JOIN messages AS x ON u.id = x.sender_id
WHERE u.username = 'User1'
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly as my second query, but I need both on one query, to have 1 result in the format I wrote in the answer. By the way, thanks for the reply

Comment: Updated, is that better?

Comment: Thanks, partially is correct but since I need both username on the result I choose as correct answer the one of @geoandri

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.username, M.receiver_id, M.sender_id, M.text 
FROM user U 
LEFT JOIN messages AS M ON  U.id = M.sender_id
```